# while editing, validation of date not working in ODOO

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

Hi I am beginner in ODOO Technology, when I click create button its validation of date is working but it is not validating where in edit mode

Answer (score 1):

Everything is correct,

create and edit are different things. Create is when you are creating object and edit is when you apply changes to already created object.

So when you are creating object function create() runs and after edit function write() will run.

During making changes none of function works what I mentioned above, you can just use onchange method to validate field after being changed or catch them in write() function and try validation there

Comment: Perhaps he meant default values/behaviour. Try to explain that, too :-)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Dachi but problem is I have used _constraints for validation so how to deal _constraints with edit or write operation.

Comment: what type of action you want to achieve with edit operation? constraints are sql side validation and you can make same type of validation in create and edit functions but I DOONT RECOMMEND IT because sql constraint are light operation while create and edit are heavy operation

Comment: @Dachi Sir but some inbuild modules using _constraints function for validation purpose so I have used in my code but while editing it's not working.

Comment: constraints working in sql side as I said. So after you edit and click save button and when python is trying to update data in sql using werzurg then magic happens and in this moment is sql constraint making validation job

Comment: I don't know exactly what type of validation you need but try onchange method